# Push Notification Expo

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

I would like to ask a question, I have an application in which I need to send many notifications per second. Expo's limit is 600 notifications per second if I'm not mistaken. I want to know how I can increase this limit, if it is paid I am willing to pay a price and increase this rate by up to 2000 notifications per second, what do I do, or who should I talk to?

I already tried to do with more than 600 notifications per second, but I get blocked by Expo. I would like to know if there is any paid plan at the expo to increase this rate.

Comment: Hello Luis, have you found a good solution? Which route did you take?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution by adding Redis into the project. I saved all the requests as queries into Redis on the backend.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate more on how you did it?